# S.M.A.R.T. showing different values than some other time before

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bad-sectors

So, maybe about a 2 years ago my Samsung F3 Spinpoint had bad sectors and I repaired what with Hard Disk Sentinel. What did that do, did it mark the sector so that OS doesn't use them? I was on Windows 7 then I think.

And then, I switch the OS, install Hard Disk Sentinel and it shows that everything is okay. How is that possible, did maybe thoes sectors got permanently marked bad?
I know that, if I format the drive all bad sectors on it are automatically marked, but I think I didn't do that.

But I was suspicious about this so I edited the offsets the way they were before (by editing offsets in Hard Disk Sentinel you mark those sectors bad).
Did I do anything bad to my hard drive by doing this, if is there really was no bad sectors.

And now I've reset those offsets and it shows that everything is okay.  Windows tool and CrystalDiskInfo also show that everything is okay.

Comment: You only mention SMART once. If you don’t remember the exact readings from before (pending vs reallocated etc), the question cannot be answered. If a sector is remapped by the drive, it stays remapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are two types of bad sectors: "hard", which are physically damaged, and "soft", which just look like corrupted to the operating system (if the error-correcting code doesn't match, for example).

There is a chance of recovering "soft" bad sectors on the drive by simply overwriting them, which is what some recovery programs do.

"soft" bad sectors can be recorded in S.M.A.R.T. of the drive, when they appear. And if they get recovered, some hard drives can reclaim the count of these sectors later. I had such situation with some old 80 Gb Samsung drive, which got one "soft" bad sector in its S.M.A.R.T. after the sudden power outage. Some time later this record disappeared from S.M.A.R.T., perhaps after the drive ran its built-in self-test.